# How to detect a type type alias?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I can detect a member using the following template check:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct hasMember : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct hasMember<T, decltype((void)T::member, void())> : std::true_type {};
```

E.g. for:

```
class Test{
public:
   int member;
   using sometype = size_t; 
}
```

I could do:

```
if constexpr(hasMember<Test>)
{
   //do something
}
```

Now suppose I need a `constexpr if` that tells me if a class has a using definition. I.e. something that could detect that some class (e.g. `test`) has a using definition of some type. I.e. something like

```
if constexpr(hasSomeType<Test>)
{
     //do something
}
```

Is this possible in c++17? How?

Comment: With C++20 `requires`, both become one-liners...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes: I am eagerly awaiting the moment when my cloud-computing platform adopts the latest GCC toolchain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by using the same method as with the data member detection. Instead of using a data member, simply use a member type and `void_t`:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct hasSomeType : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct hasSomeType<T, std::void_t<typename T::member_type>> : std::true_type {};
```

Alternatively you can use the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected):

```
template<typename T>
using member_type_t = typename T::member_type;
```

You can put any expression there using `decltype`.

Then, use the alias to perform the detection:

```
if constexpr (is_detected<member_type_t, Test>) {
    // ...
}
```

Of course, in C++20, all of this becomes one liners:

```
// requires a type
if constexpr (requires(Test) { typename Test::member_type; }) {

}

// requires a member
if constexpr (requires(Test t) { t.member; }) {

}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/u-EQhx)